# AWS Server Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm new in AWS. For one project we require to purchase server on AWS. I don't know what configuration is required for the server. Our website will be like https://www.justdial.com/ and minimum 1000 users every time will be online on the website. Please, what configuration will be best with minimum pricing. I'm mentioning details below, what we want;

```
>     • 1 - Elastic IP 
>     • 1 - Load Balancer
>     • 2 - Webserver + autoscaling
>     • 1 - Database SQL
>     • 1 - S3 storage backup 
>     • CDN
```

if anything else is missing please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Go for micro-service architecture, and create `labmda` for every service. You can use private RDS for security. Using labmda based `serverless` approach will cost you on the basis of API request per API. Since during night time request reduces to close to zero, for that duration you wont be charged. AWS lambda auto balance load and availability of service to everyone with minimum CPU, memory usage. You won't be needing your load balanced as AWS does it by default.

Based upon your requirements use of a VM won't be a good idea, as most of these, Load-Balancer, Webserver autoscaling, are free for serverless lambda, and using RDS will put your database cost to minimum in place of owning a VM and scaling VM resources.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your application. If all you do is return static pages, you might be fine with the smallest instance and CDN like CloudFront. If every request is dynamic and takes massive computations, you need some strong servers.

I suggest you start with some reasonable settings (e.g. `t3.medium`) and then load-test it to figure out what you really need. There are many tools for that. You basically need something that will generate a lot of requests to your servers and track errors, latency and total response time. If any of those metrics come back insufficient (this also depends on your needs), add more resources. Make sure to leave room for traffic spikes.

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply.  For load balancer and web server, instance will be same or any change required. what about database

Comment: Same answer. Depends on your needs and you should run tests to find out the best size for you.